# Angular and TypeScript/javascript singletons in several different browser tabs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My question has to do with whether TypeScript singleton class (used as a MVC model type of object) in my Angular app into one tab in  browser will be the same or a different object then the same singleton  loaded into another tab in the same browser instance.

The implementation looks sort of like this (similar idea could be written in JS):

```
[TypeScript]
class Budget {
    readonly name : string;

    private static instance: Budget;
    static getInstance(name? : string) {
        if (!this.instance) {
            name = name ? name : "no name";
            this.instance = new Budget(name);
        }
        return this.instance;
    }
    private constructor(name : string) {
      this.name = name;
    }
 }
```

In my application, the top level  "Budget" object is written as a singleton to ease access to a  various data items, class instances, etc. The budget object is composed of about 40 other component classes which need to access each other, and the Budget object provides ways for each class instance to access the others it needs.   The singleton architecture allows me to write code like Budget.getInstance().getAccount("foo") instead of maintaining a reference to a Budget instance in all of these sub-classes. This turns out to make it a lot easier for me to write.

My question is whether or not with this architecture a user could open two different budgets in different tabs of a browser (Chrome, say)  which refer to different Budget object instances that have different names. (The singleton instance is populated with data by a rails backend depending on which budget the user wants to edit.)  I can imagine where it will be useful for a user to refer to two different budgets at the same time in the browser,  where each is in a different tab. But this would not be possible if there is actually only one Budget object accessible within the all the browser tabs.

Comment: Static is always in memory. This means there is only one intance.

Comment: You can use  local storage of browser to write/read shared data

Comment: I actually don't want to share the data.  I was hoping that there would be separate memory spaces for each tab so I could have the a distinct singleton instance in each tab, but if John is right, that isn't possible.

Comment: John, are you certain about this?  I tried an experiment in Angular on Chrome, and it seems that there is actually a different singleton instance in each browser tab.  Which would make a certain amount of sense; given the little I know about browser security it would be weird/dangerous if a process running in one tab would interact with another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can share JavaScript objects between tabs if the second tab is opened from the first tab with `window.open()`. This function returns the `window` object of the opened tab.

Althought this there is no built-in Angular way to do this, you can try it yourself with native JavaScript:

- Open the browser's console, then type `const secondTab = window.open('', '_blank');`
- Create an object on the first tab: `const obj = {};`
- Assign it to the second tab with `secondTab.obj = obj;`
- In the second tab, type `obj.prop = 'test';`
- In the first tab, type `obj`, you'll notice that it has been modified by the second tab

If your question is about tabs that are opened independently, I'm afraid this is not possible.

Comment: My point is I -don't- want to share the singleton.  Are you saying that by default the singletons are distinct?  That woudl be good if true.

Comment: Yes they are. Every tab has its own JavaScript context